# JQuery (notification) event does not get fired

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a notification using JQuery when clicked on a button.

```
<input type="submit" runat="server" id="submit_click" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
```

Associated event should get fired by this :

```
$('#submit_click').click(function()
```

But it does not...
I've also tried giving,

```
$('body').on('click', '#submit_click', function (e) {...........});
```

Please check the below JSFiddle:

**JSFiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/tj5a5bnk/1/

**UPDATE :**
Please check this :

**JSFiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/tj5a5bnk/16/

I have added the required libraries....the notification should ideally pop-up from the side and close when clicked on it...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because you didn't include jQuery or the Noty library. Add both of those and it appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/tj5a5bnk/2/

Comment: You haven't included jquery in fiddle.  updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tj5a5bnk/3/

Comment: updated in fiddle, please check  https://jsfiddle.net/tj5a5bnk/14/

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Oh! I see! Thanks! I'm new to JQuery...
But, the notification does not "close" when clicked?

Comment: @AshleyR. no problem. You're probably best to just delete this question as it was just a configuration issue that's not likely to help any future visitors.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan in the JSFiddle you provided, the notification does not "close" on clicking....It should close, right? Close function is defined inside new Noty{....

Comment: Hi, Check my answer ..i told to use document.Ready..for this ..I have provided working code in jsfiddle in my answer ..can you please check it ounce

Comment: if it works for you please do accept/upvote answer...

Comment: check working code here :  https://jsfiddle.net/tj5a5bnk/16/ please do accept/upvote answer if works for you

Comment: can you please check jsfiddle provided by me ...

Comment: @PranayRana You have pasted the link to MY fiddle. Can you please check and provide the link to yours? 
P.S. I think you did not update the fiddle after you made the changes..

Comment: @AshleyR. - its not about jsfiddle link ...my point is to make use of document.Ready() and attache event in that , because you can attach event to element after you dom get ready...in Jsfiddle you have option where you say run my code after dom get ready..but in production i.e. in you application browser you dont have that opt ..that is provided by document.Reay() that is my point ..hope you get it

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the jquery library, hence it was not working! Add the library by giving CDN url for jquery in the left hand side of the fiddle, under `External Resources`.

[Jquery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js).

[Updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tj5a5bnk/5/).

Answer (score -1):

jsfiddle working code : https://jsfiddle.net/tj5a5bnk/16/
problem with this is you missed some end `}` `var mojsShow = function (promise) {` function

---

this is working code or you : on jsfiddel : https://jsfiddle.net/tj5a5bnk/6/  , you forget to select javascript libarary in Jsfiddle.

and wrapped you code inside document.Ready , i do suggest you make use of document.Ready - because it get called when your document is ready and created and than you can access dom element and attache your event

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
///your code
});
```

Comment: why there -1 ???is there any reason ...in real time code you dont have jsfiddle ...there you need document.Ready..in Jsfiddle you set things to execute on dom ready thats y you dont need event ...

Comment: jsfiddle is trying environment ....you could not code in jsfiddle ...so my answer is based on code you write in production ...

Comment: Strange that it got a -1. I upvoted the ans to neutralize.

Answer (score -2):

Please try these :

```
$("#submit_click").on("click",function(){

alert('Yepeee it is working ');
});
```

Comment: This is logically identical to the `click()` method which the OP states they already used